# Insert third column using sed regex

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to insert a third column using sed, where the column separator is the bar character '|'. The problem is the total number of columns in the text is unknown but at least 2. For example, I want to add the third column with the text 'foo':

```
abc|def ---> abc|def|foo
abc|def|jkl ---> abc|def|foo|jkl
```

I prefer `sed` because of the `-i` option, and I guess I can do it with `awk` with some copying.

I tried:

```
$ echo "abc|def|jkl" | sed -r 's/^(.*|)(.*)([|$])/\1\2|foo\3/' 
abc|def|foo|jkl
```

but this didn't work with two columns:

```
$ echo "abc|def" | sed -r 's/^(.*|)(.*)([|$])/\1\2|foo\3/' 
abc|foo|def
```

I tried some other codes also, but I guess this was my best attempt.

Answer (score 2):

depending on the resources provided i have just edited some parts of your regex and made a bare-bone solution out of it which may work as intended.

The use of boolean `OR` i.e. `|` can be done in the regex grouping third part of your regex equation.

This solution is working with only the above examples given by you.

`echo "abc|def" | sed -r 's/(.*\|)(.*)(\|.*|$)/\1\2|foo\3/'`

the output attained:

`abc|def|foo`

other part:

`echo "abc|def|jkl" | sed -r 's/(.*\|)(.*)(\|.*|$)/\1\2|foo\3/'`

output:

`abc|def|foo|jkl`

The outlier part (giving extra parts after `|`):

`echo "abc|def|jkl|asd" | sed -r 's/(.*\|)(.*)(\|.*|$)/\1\2|foo\3/'`

the output:

`abc|def|jkl|foo|asd`

Edit:
more accurate regex to insert into third column everytime.

`echo "abc|def|jkl|asd|kjfwk" | sed -r 's/^([a-z]*\|[a-z]*\|)(.*)/\1foo|\2/'`

Answer (score 1):

Using the *`n`* flag of `s` to substitute second match of `anything other than '|' character`:

```
sed 's/[^|]*/&|foo/2' file
```

For cases where there is only single column an empty second column could be added:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/[^|]*/&|foo/2;t' -e 's/$/|/;t a' file
```

Checking:

```
$ cat file
xyz
xyz|uvw|rst|opq|lmn
abc|def
abc|def|jkl
$ sed ':a
> s/[^|]*/&|foo/2;t
> s/$/|/;t a' file
xyz||foo
xyz|uvw|foo|rst|opq|lmn
abc|def|foo
abc|def|foo|jkl
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!